# .batファイルから起動された.exeファイルを強制終了させたい

Tags: python

以下のように、run.batファイルと、test.exeファイルがあり、run.batをPython経由で実行します。

**run.bat**

```
SETLOCAL
SET PATH=%PATH%;..\..\samples\external\opencv\bin;..\..\bin;
test.exe
```

**python_test.py**

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

from os import path
import subprocess

runPath = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'run.bat')
process = subprocess.Popen(runPath)

import time
time.sleep(10)

import signal
import psutil
try:
    os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)

except:
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())

try:
    parent = psutil.Process(process.pid)
    for child in parent.children(recursive=True):
        child.kill()
    parent.kill()
except:
    import traceback
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

exeファイルを直接popenで開いた場合は、戻り値でexeファイルのprocess.pidが得られるので強制終了できるのですが、.batファイルを経由するとそれが出来ませんでした。

エラー内容は次の通りです。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\python_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    parent = psutil.Process(process.pid)
  File "C:\Users\Documents\WPy64-31040\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 332, in __init__
    self._init(pid)
  File "C:\Users\Documents\WPy64-31040\python-3.10.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\psutil\__init__.py", line 373, in _init
    raise NoSuchProcess(pid, msg='process PID not found')
psutil.NoSuchProcess: process PID not found (pid=10976)
```

強制終了用の.batファイルも試して実行してみましたが終了できませんでした。

**taskkill.bat**

```
taskkill /F /T /IM test.exe
```

Pythonの実行環境はWinPythonです。
強制終了させる方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: 提示されたソースコード上では、その前に`os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)`で既に終了させているからとか？

Comment: そのようでした。順序を逆にしたら終了できました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちらもコメントで解決したようなので、内容を回答として記述しておきます。

提示されたソースコード上では、その前に`os.kill(process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)`で既に終了させているために該当のプロセスが存在しないので例外になっているということでしょう。

`psutil`による`kill()`の処理と`os.kill()`の処理順番を逆にすれば終了出来たとのこと。

---

ただし少し疑問点もあります。

`psutil`による`kill()`の処理で元のプロセスを`parent.kill()`でkillしているように見えるため、処理順番を変えたということはその後に同じ元のプロセスのpidに対して`os.kill()`していることになり、そちらでは例外が発生しなかったのだろうか？ ということです。
まあ例外が発生していないのなら問題は無いのでしょう。

---

もう一つ、参考情報としてこんな記事があります。
[subprocessを子プロセスまでkillして停止させる (python)](https://dlrecord.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/07/13/214241)

> Windows
> シンプルに`kill()`メソッドを呼べば、シェルが実行した外部コマンドも止まります。
>
> ```
> cmd = "some shell command"      # シェル実行のコマンド
> p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
> p.kill()
> ```

ということなので、質問のソースコードでは`subprocess.Popen()`の戻り値が`process`に格納されているので、もしかしたら`process.kill()`だけですべて終了出来る可能性があります。
試してみてください。